# mysql - Where do we find a temporary table in the MySQL Navigator?

Tags: mysql

I just want to see where is it located. I am NOT asking how to use it. I am not looking for a `select` statement as an answer. I just want to see the table, like we see temporary tables in SQL Server Object Explorer. Tried finding it online, but surprisingly there is no solution to this very basic question.

Comment: Mysql use system default, for Unix it get the value of variable env TMPDIR, being "/tmp", "/var/tmp/" or "usr/tmp", the same with Windows %temp%, being "c:/windows/temp".

Comment: only when the temporary table is converted to a disk based temporary @MauroAlexandre these dirs will not contain temporary tables which run in the memory..

Comment: Yes, but is a complex term to explain as a short comment.

I reccomend you reading https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/internal-temporary-tables.html

Comment: also  i believe the dirs might contain a `.frm` (table structure) file when the temporary table is running in memory. @MauroAlexandre .. Topicstarter MySQL does not have a good method to query for existing temporary tables unless you program it in yourself offcource.